# I need a custom quick setting tile, similar to the wifi selection feature

Tags: java, android, android-app-quick-setting

I am trying to create a custom quick setting tile, I want to implement it so that it has an arrow next to it. When clicked on the arrow, a box pops up showing selection，but it's not a dialog

[It looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WghEO.jpg)

[When I click on it, it's going to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuJJa.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.